# LLenar datagrid wpf C# con relacion de tablas en entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf

Estoy tratando de llegar un datagrid en wpf relacionando datos de otras tablas con entity framework, y no me ha sido posible, ya que la descripción de la tabla tiene el mismo nombre de columna y cuando realizo el join me dice que un tipo anónimo no puede tener varias propiedades con el mismo nombre, cuando lo hago con un solo join si funciona, al incluir el segundo ya me lanza el error, esta es la consulta

```
using (EntityDB.CONTROLEntities db = new EntityDB.CONTROLEntities())
{
    var query=(from w in db.calendarios
        join u in db.modulos   on w.modulo equals u.id
        join m in db.plantas on w.planta equals m.id
        select new { w.id,w.usuario, u.nombre,m.nombre }).ToList();

        dgvasignar_datos.ItemsSource = query;
}
```

si quito el join de las plantas funciona, pero al agregar otro join no me lo permite.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendaria definas una clase para que la entidad que listas en el grid

```
public class calendario{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string usuario {get;set;}
    public string planta {get;set;}
    public string modulo {get;set;}
}
```

entonces usarias en el linq

```
using (EntityDB.CONTROLEntities db = new EntityDB.CONTROLEntities())
{
    var query=(from w in db.calendarios
        join u in db.modulos   on w.modulo equals u.id
        join m in db.plantas on w.planta equals m.id
        select new calendario(){ 
             Id = w.id,
             usuario = w.usuario, 
             modulo = u.nombre,
             planta = m.nombre 
        }).ToList();

        dgvasignar_datos.ItemsSource = query;
}
```

Recuerda cambiar el `binding` en el `xaml` para que las columnas del grid coincidan con estas propiedades